# onKeyDown handler function works only once

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, user-input

I  created a `chack` keyboard click function instead of declaring event listeners all the time.

When you call it once it works but when I have two or more instances only the last one works right.

```
var left = y_input_s.chack (y_key.left);
var right =  y_input_s.chack (y_key.right);
```

Only "right" works.

This is the function:

```
y_input.prototype.chack = function (key) 
{

//38 up |40 down| 39 left | right 37 | space 32 | 

//insert key code to array dinamicly

//if its unudetfid so the key wasent pressed yet so its false
if(y_input.prototype.key_down_cack[key] == undefined)
{
    y_input.prototype.key_down_cack[key] = false;   
}

//if the key is down change its place in array to true
document.onkeydown = function(event)
{

    if(event.keyCode == key){y_input.prototype.key_down_cack[key] = true;}

}

//if the key is up change its place in array to false
document.onkeyup = function(event)
{
    if(event.keyCode == key){y_input.prototype.key_down_cack[key] = false;}
}

//return the key state from array

return y_input.prototype.key_down_cack[key] ;
    }//end chack
```

I tested stuff inside the function the value of "key" is fine, but when I chack "key" inside.

```
document.onkeydown = function(event)
{
```

It returns the last `chack` function key value that was passed in the argument.

Comment: What is `chack`? Is it meant to be `check`?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5595554/ might help you

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it fails is you keep writing over the keyup event.

```
document.onkeyup = function(event)
```

Learn about [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener)